# Apple pay money not withdraw

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, applepay

We have app in the App Store. When user have pay, the payment is success but money not withdraw from credit card. What can be a problem? Maybe we need add bank information or something like this?

```
if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: supportedPaymentNetworks) {
             let request = PKPaymentRequest(
             request.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.my_app_identifier"
             request.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
             request.countryCode = "RU"
             request.currencyCode = "RUR"

             request.supportedNetworks = supportedPaymentNetworks
             request.paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: egrn.name, amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: price))]

             let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)!
             applePayController.delegate = delegate
             self.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you contact Apple?

Comment: The payment can be successful but not a posted transaction yet if using credit cards.. If using debit, it is immediate.. When using credit, it can take 5 business days to process a transaction. However, your best bet is to verify this with Apple..

Comment: did u resolve this issue? because facing this issue right now